# Where are there female centaurs in mythology?

Tags: greek, mythical-creatures

A few months ago, I was reading the *Metamorphoses* by Ovid (translator unknown). At a time I was reading it just to get through it because it wasn't what I expected (still read it though, albeit not thoroughly). Anyways, I dimly remember a picture of a female centaur.

What are the myths around female centaurs?

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia has a nice article about the [Centaurides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaurides), or centauresses, the female centaurs.

> First encountered in Greek mythology as members of the tribe of the
>   Centauroi, the Centaurides are only occasionally mentioned in written
>   sources, but appear frequently in Greek art and Roman mosaics. The
>   centauress who appears most frequently in literature is Hylonome, wife
>   of the centaur Cyllarus.

In the [Literary depictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaurides#Literary_depictions) section of the same article there are two quotes, the first from Philostratus the Elder:

> How beautiful the Centaurides are, even where they are horses; for
>   some grow out of white mares, others are attached to chestnut mares,
>   and the coats of others are dappled, but they glisten like those of
>   horses that are well cared for. There is also a white female Centaur
>   that grows out of a black mare, and the very opposition of the colours
>   helps to produce the united beauty of the whole.

And in the *Metamorphoses*, Ovid says this about [Hylonome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylonome):

> In the high woods there was none comelier of all the centaur-girls,
>   and she alone by love and love’s sweet words and winning ways held
>   Cyllarus, yes, and the care she took to look her best (so far as that
>   may be with limbs like that). She combed her glossy hair, and twined
>   her curls in turn with rosemary or violets or roses, and sometimes she
>   wore a pure white lily. Twice a day she bathed her face in the clear
>   brook that fell from Pagasae’s high forest, twice she plunged her body
>   in its flow, nor would she wear on her left side and shoulder any skin
>   but what became her from best-chosen beasts.

[Ovid, Metamorphoses, 12.316 ff.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0028%3Abook%3D12%3Acard%3D316)

Theoi.com has also a small entry for the [Centaurides (Kentaurides)](http://www.theoi.com/Georgikos/Kentaurides.html), with longer extracts from the same sources.

Comment: [Ovid, *Metamorphoses*, 12.316 ff.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0028%3Abook%3D12%3Acard%3D316)